# Выходит ошибка SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Недавно начал  учить язык .Не знаю в чем дело. Еще скажитье правильно ли я посчитал  проценты ?

Comment: Скобку закрывающую забыли `food = int(input('''`... ниже в конце одна скобка

Comment: Код и ошибка в вопросе должны быть в текстовом виде.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не закрыли скобку.Долно быть так

```
food = int(input('''какой-то текст''')) #вот здесь
```

И также вы сравниваете строку с целым числом. Должно быть так:

```
if food == 1:
```

И аналогично в других местах